# AngularJS + Bootstrap Modals on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a single-page-application using AngularJS, supported by Bootstrap. But Bootstrap is mainly used for modal dialogs. My DOM consists of various absolutely placed nested divs.

It works fine on most browsers, except for iOS (even the Windows Safari does it correctly) - but I have the problem, that on iPad the modal-backdrop is behind certain other elements.

The most common answer I found was to move the modals outside "everything". However this is not easily possible, since most of them are Angular directives that depend on the scope they are in.

The buildup looks something like this:

```
<header>..</header> <!-- position absolute -->
<content> <!-- position absolute -->
    <sidebar>..</sidebar> <!-- position absolute -->
    <part> <!-- position absolute -->
        <button ng-click="openModal()">Click</button>
        <my-modal parent="part"></my-modal>
    </part>
</content>
```

part is a "wrapper" that manages the display of data.

my-modal is an Angular directive, whose template looks like a standard Bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" class="my-modal-finder">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>...</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

openModal basically looks for "my-modal" and then uses $('.my-modal-finder').modal('show'). As mentioned: on iPad, the header and the sidebar are shown over the backdrop and the modal content.

I have already updated to Bootstrap 3.3.2.

I suppose I could write two directives "my-modal-init" and "my-modal", where "my-modal-init" compiles the contents of "my-modal" and appends them to $('body') - and cleans up on $destroy.
This does feel rather hacky though, so I'd rather not.

Does anyone have experience with this problem and knows of a better solution?